# Powers of complex permutation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I am looking for $P^{100}$, where

$$
P=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & i & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & i \\
        i & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}.
$$

The cycle repeats for $P^{13} = P$ and I find $P^{100}=P^{4}$. Is there a way to arrive at this answer quicker than by computing $P^2, P^3, \dots P^{13}$?

Comment: Since $P=i M$ where $M$ is real, we have $P^{100}=i^{100}M^{100}=M^{100}$. So $i$ really plays no role here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just compute $P^2$ and $P^3$, then you are done because of
$$
P^3=-\begin{pmatrix} i & 0 & 0 \cr 0 & i & 0 \cr 0 & 0 & i\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Of course, this matrix to the power of $4$ is the identity, and no smaller power, because no smaller power of $-i$ is equal to $1$.

Answer (score 3):

The characteristic polynomial of this matrix is $-x^3 - i$. We know (Cayley-Hamilton) that $P$ satisfies $-P^3 - iI = 0$, so $P^3 = -iI$ and $P^{12} = (-i)^4I = I$.

Comment: Depends on preference I suppose. I'd rather calculate the determinant of a 3x3 matrix than calculate a third power of it.

Comment: I agree. Depends on the knowledge of the rule of Sarrus, too. That's fairly quick. And, of course, whether or not you know what a characteristic polynomial is.

Comment: @Sirzh: $P^3=-iI$.

Comment: Huh, I wrote that but someone edited it. Fixing it again now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$A = \begin{bmatrix}0& 1 &0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0\end{bmatrix}$
and 
$A^2 = \begin{bmatrix}0& 0 &1\\1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$

$A^3 = I$

$P = iA, P^2 = -A^2, P^3 = -iI,$  etc.
I see something isomorphic to $Z_4 \times Z_3$